# "Inactive" views won't update background color

Tags: ios, view, colors, background

I have this strange issue (or I think so). I have two views. One is the "base" view and another is for settings, and I want to change there background color to pattern image. This works fine, but when I placed some buttons to let the user choose which color they want to see. My current code looks like

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"Green" forKey:@"Theme"];
NSString *bgString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_bg.png", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Theme"]];
self.baseView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:bgString]];
self.settingsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:bgString]];
```

For some reason, only the settingsView update. SettingsView is inside popover, but I have tried in view controller as well. When I quit and re-open the app, then it is updated. How can I get it updated immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Try `[[self settingsView] setNeedsDisplay]`

Comment: I tried this, didn't work, I even did it on the completion of dismissing the view controller, still no effect. I actually tried to place the same code I use in the action to the completion, still nothing. This is getting more strange...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any background threads or a lot of work that possibly locks up the UI? Try using this to make sure it runs on the main thread and see how that goes.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    //Your code here
                });
```